# Надо ли избавляться от всех ретурнов в node-js?

Tags: node.js, асинхронность

Здравствуйте, я тут дипломную работу на ноджс пишу и возник такой вопрос: по идее всё должно быть неблокирующее, и функции должны вызываться исключительно по коллбэкам, или по событиям, но есть такие маленькие функции, типа посчитать сумму массива (условно), которые выполняются очень быстро и ради них не хочется распиливать одну большую, красивую, логичную функцию на цепочку коллбэков. Так и вот: можно ли такие функции маленькие оставлять с ретурнами, и ждать от них ответа, как буд-то они типа инлайновые?

Comment: не совсем все, все IO операции

Comment: То есть, например, у меня есть кусок, где считается куча математики. Математика - удел процессора, обращений к диску там нигде нет, следовательно внутри может быть сколько хочешь вызовов функций с ретурнами, которые тоже только в оперативке?

Comment: угу.

Представляю как ты писал код до этого. Там совершенно атомная лапша, да?

Comment: =)
Нет, это мой первый проэкт на ноджс, и я с самого начала всю математику сделал с ретурнами ибо не очень втыкал в асинхронный стиль, потом почитал, погуглил, и на сонную голову подумал, что всё, пипец, надо всё переделывать, а утром сегодня на свежую голову понял, что это же просто кусок кода как-бы цельный выходит и всё, и переделал только моменты обращения к базе и к кэшу.

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать погуглить про словам "Node.js is a cancer". Была такая провокационная [статья](http://pages.citebite.com/b2x0j8q1megb), после которой все кинулись писать сервера для вычисления чисел Фибоначчи, мериться результатами и рассуждать, что правильнее. Вот, например https://github.com/glenjamin/node-fib

Если я правильно понял идею, суть в том, что при интенсивном потоке тяжелых (математических) запросов время, потраченное на вычисление ответа, становится не так уж важно. Все равно ответ вы будете вычислять долго. Гораздо важнее, чтобы клиенты получали ответ через одно и то же время, и именно для этого нужно использовать много асинхронных вызовов.

Comment: смысл в том, что нодовский скрипт парсит инет на предмет картинок, и потом над этими картинками производит математические операции. Но в этом же потоке работает веб-сервер, который должен обрабатывать запросы пользователей.

Comment: Я бы вообще посоветовал разделить на две части. Веб-морда отдельно, парсер-обработчик отдельно. Между собой, в случае необходимости, общаются любым из мириада методов IPC.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего комментатора. Судя по Вашим описаниям - это две разные задачи, всего лишь требующие одну и ту же БД.